Examples of small resolutions in dimension 4 and higher
I have seen numerous examples of 3-folds admitting small resolutions. Are there similar examples in higher dimension? In particular, I am looking for examples of singular varieties of dimension $4$ and higher that admit small resolutions. Any reference will be most welcome.

Consider the projective cone $X$ over $\mathbb{P}^m \times \mathbb{P}^n$. Then
$$
\tilde{X} := \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^m}\Big(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus (n+1)}\Big)
$$
is a small resolution of $X$.

Thank you|! Are there also examples of hypersurfaces in dimension 4 or higher that have a small resolution?

If you mean hypersurfaces with isolated singularities, then no. Because any small resolution is the projective spectrum of a graded algebra associated with a reflexive sheaf of rank 1 which is not invertible, and hypersurfaces do not have such sheaves by Samuel's Conjecture (proved by Grothendieck).

No, I do not mean isolated singularities.

Then the hypersurface $x_1x_2 - x_3x_4 = 0$ in $\mathbb{A}^5$ has a small resolution.

Thanks Sasha, for the examples!
